TypeScript Error: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request' when trying to access req.user in Express
I’m working on an Express application with TypeScript, and I’m running into an issue where TypeScript does not recognize the user property on the Request object. Specifically, I’m getting the following error in my controller:
src/controllers/user.controller.ts:107:15 - error TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.

107       if (req.user) {
        

Here is the relevant part of my controller code:
export const getUserDetails = AsyncHandler(
  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      if (req.user) {  // <-- Error happens here
        const user = await getUserDetailsService(req.user.id, req.user.email);
        res.status(200).json({ success: true, user });
      } else {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('User not authenticated', 401));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler('Internal server error', 500));
    }
  }
);

I know that req.user is being set in my authentication middleware like this:
export const isAuthenticated = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const token = req.cookies.access_token;
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Not authenticated' });
  }
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string) as UserData;
    req.user = decoded;  // Setting req.user here
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Token is not valid' });
  }
};



Extending the Express Request interface:
I created a file to extend the Request interface so that user is recognized:
// src/@types/express/index.d.ts
import { UserData } from '../interfaces/user'; // Adjust the path

declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user?: UserData;  // Making it optional
  }
}



Updated tsconfig.json:
I ensured that TypeScript includes my custom type definitions:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/@types/**/*.d.ts"]
}


Restarted TypeScript Compiler:
After making these changes, I restarted my TypeScript compiler (ts-node, nodemon), but the issue persists.


What am I missing to properly extend the Request interface to include the user property? Is there something else I need to configure to get this working?
Additional information:

TypeScript version: 4.0+
Express version: 4.x
I’m using @types/express for type definitions.


Well, you should definitely blame the guys that created the middleware: the are not allowed to change the shape of an object that they don't own.
